# Compiler does not warn when dereferencing nullptr

Tags: c++, null, compiler-warnings, dereference

This:

```
int* p = nullptr;
auto tmp = *p;
```

doesn't cause neither gcc 4.6 nor VS2010 sp1 to issue at least a warning. Is there any option in any of those compilers to make them issue a warning in cases like this? I test-compiled in VS with /w4.

Answer (score 8):

It's not illegal, it's just undefined behaviour.

Turning on warnings for this might cause a false sense of security, because often it is not known until runtime if some pointer points to `nullptr` or to something else. Valgrind can check for these errors (and many more).

Not to mention it would dramatically increase compile times.

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio 2010 SP1 (don't know which edition you need), run Code Analysis. I just tried with your exact code, and it shows warning 6011:

```
warning C6011: NULL-Zeiger "p" wird dereferenziert.: Lines: 138, 139
```

Comment: @MarsonMao: Yes, it's German - that's why it's actually a good thing that MS compilers have a warning/error number. This way you can search for "warning CXXXX" even though you might not find the text anywhere (the text contains identifiers anyway), unlike certain other compilers.

Answer (score 4):

"Cases like this" are quite obscure, and it would require the compiler to backtrack from *every* de-reference and see if it can prove that it knows that the pointer has a constant, and invalid, value.

Consider that some other piece of the program could be given a pointer to the pointer (aliasing) and overwrite it in a different code path, or (worse) on a different thread.

It's not easy to detect, and I think the cost in terms of compilation time for real-world programs would make it not worth it, if it even could be implemented with a reasonable amount of effort.

Comment: GCC does do dataflow analysis with -O1 or better. I don't think this suggested warning is technically any more or less difficult to analyse than `-Wuninitialized`, just to warn as in the example where a pointer is initialized to null and then used in a particular way (dereferencing it). Of course it would be harder (impossible in general) to spot cases where a null pointer is passed to some other function, which in turn dereferences it. GCC also does some dataflow tracking of whether pointers *mustn't be* null, for `-fdelete-null-pointer-checks`, just not AFAIK whether they *are* null

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Knowing that the pointer has been initialized and knowing that the value it has been initialized to is not `nullptr` are not the same problem. As you already mention, you can do `int *p = ...; int *q = p; int i = *q;` It is *simple* to verify that the local variable `q` has been initialized (you only need information in this context) it is much harder to track that the value initialized to *may be* `nullptr`. Also, the `-Wuninitialized`, IIRC is not guaranteed to kick in, i.e. it will pick uninitialized many times, creating a sense of security, but will fail sometimes.

Comment: There are some more complex static analysis tools that provide better results *clang analyzer* being one of them, but they are much slower to run, and while they would pick uninitialized values, they cannot guarantee that `int *p = foo();` is not a `nullptr` (unless `foo` is defined in the same translation unit, and even then it might depend on other arguments...). The complexity of the problem is much worse than initialization.

Comment: @dribeas: sure, if the question is "identify all dereferences of null pointers", then we know that's equivalent to the halting problem. All I mean to point out is that this is not in general a convincing argument against warnings that require this kind of analysis: at least, not convincing to the authors of GCC. The questioner's given example would be trivial to detect, and we could construct examples which are impossible to detect, just like `-Wuninitialized`.

Answer (score 2):

valgrind can point this out. I use it to check for this kind of obscure cases, and invalid reads/writes.

Answer (score 1):

This is runtime error, not compile time error. Compiler can catch such dereferences only in very limited cases where it can be completely sure you about pointer value. There is just no point for added complexity.

Answer (score 1):

That is an undefined behaviour. That means the compiler is not required to issue a warning or error.

Answer (score 0):

Dereferencing a null pointer is undefined behavior. The compiler is allowed to diagnose such cases but is not required to.